# how to deal with certificate issue in windows 8.1?

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

recently I was working with some facebook api and programs, and I upgrade my windows 8.0 OS to windows 8.1 OS and when I run the program I get this errors in IE11.

```
Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate. 

For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in Internet Explorer Help.
```

how can I solve certificate issue? "how to add certificate if needed"

Answer (score 0):

Open IE Tools > Internet Options > Content tab, then select the **Certificates** button. From there you can go through the applicable Cert types including:

- Personal
- Other People
- Intermediate Certification Authorities
- Trusted Root Certification Authorities
- Trusted Publishers
- Untrusted Publishers

As you mentioned "working with some facebook api and programs" check in the Untrusted Publishers section.

You can also right-click on the Windows icon and select **Run**, then type: certmgr.msc and go through your certificates in there as well.